# Image editing: What kind of transformation is this?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have 3 images and their pixels are represented by a letter in this example.

```
A B   A B   K H 
C D   E F   J I
```

I would like to map the left column of the first image to the rest of the images.

```
A B   A B   A H  
C D   C F   C I
```

What kind of transformation is this called?

What will be the command for this in imagemagick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a composition (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#over) with an alpha channel defined to keep only the first column of the first image.